# "No module named 'fitz'" error, even with PyMuPDF installed, 'fitz' uninstalled, conda environment activated and interpreter chosen

Tags: python, pymupdf

I am trying to run a program using the PyMuPDF library, which must be imported under the name 'fitz'.

I am running VSCode in MacOS 13.4, with python 3.11.4.

What are the next best steps to troubleshoot?

I have selected the correct conda virtual environment as the interpreter, and also activated the environment in Terminal. In addition, I have ran the command <conda list --name myenv>, which has shown that indeed, PyMuPDF (and pymupdfB) are installed, and fitz is NOT installed.

Comment: As an aside, you can also use `import fitz_new as fitz` to use the new ("rebased") PyMuPDF implementation, which will replace the current, "classic" one in the near future. Maybe that already helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Writing this as an answer because posting a comment fails.]

I've seen problems like this after mistakenly installing the `fitz` package and then removing it. Can you try again in a clean Conda environment?

Also, can you list the contents of your Conda environment's `fitz` directory? I'm not familiar with Conda, but a Python `venv` will have a directory called `.../lib/python3.10/site-packages/fitz/`, so there is probably a similar directory in Conda.